# Is there a proper class $X$ such that $X\subsetneq \operatorname{Ord}$?

Tags: ordinals

We already know that the class of ordinals (denoted by $\operatorname{Ord}$) is too big to be a set. I wonder if there is a sub class of $\operatorname{Ord}$ that is not a set.

**My question:** Is there a **proper** class $X$ such that $X\subsetneq \operatorname{Ord}$?

Thank you so much for your dedicated help!

Comment: The set of all sets contains sets that are not ordinals. In particular$\{3\}$

Comment: @leibnewtz It's "$\subsetneq$," not "$\not\subseteq$" - the OP is asking about proper subclasses of $Ord$ ("I wonder if there is a sub class of Ord that is not a set.").

Comment: Ah yeah thanks for the correction. In that case take every other ordinal

Comment: I encourage you to clarify which set theory you are asking about, for example [NBG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory), though I'd expect the same kinds of examples will generally apply.  It is also good to make clear what definition *Ord* has (as a proper class).

Comment: @hardmath I'm so sorry for this late reply! I'm studying ZFC set theory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The class of all non-empty ordinals is a subclass of $\operatorname{Ord}$ different from $\operatorname{Ord}$. Of course, it isn't a set. In general, a subclass $X$ of $\operatorname{Ord}$ is not a set if and only if for all ordinals $\alpha$ there is some $\beta\in X$ such that $\alpha\in \beta$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why *it isn't a set*?

Comment: @LeAnhDung Otherwise, $\operatorname{Ord}=\bigcup X$ would be a set.

Comment: I got it. Is it fine if i reason: If $X$ was a set, then $\operatorname{Ord}=X\cup\{0\}$ would be a set.

Comment: @LeAnhDung You can also think of it as: if the class $A$ of non-empty ordinals were a set, then $A\cup\{\emptyset\}$ would also be a set - but that's just $Ord$. Basically, removing a set from a proper class will always leave a proper class (analogously to removing a finite set from an infinite set).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Did you mean: If $V$ is a proper class and $X$ is a set, then $V\setminus X$ is a proper class?

Comment: @LeAnhDung I wouldn't use "$V$" to denote an arbitrary proper class, since in set theory it's always used to denote the class of all sets, but yes.

Comment: Thank you so much for your clarification @NoahSchweber! I got it.